# skipfish - error in make

Tags: security, ubuntu-12.04, skipfish

I'm trying to use skipfish on ubuntu latest version that I just downloaded. I'm following the instruction from this link http://digitivity.org/943/how-to-install-google-skipfish-on-ubuntu-linux

When I run "nice make" based on the article, I got this error below... Could anyone please help me to give some pointers to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
michaelsync@ubuntu:~/Downloads/skipfish-2.09b$ nice make
cc -L/usr/lib/ssl/engines -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/ssl/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/opt/local/lib src/skipfish.c -o skipfish \
        -O3 -Wno-format -Wall -funsigned-char -g -ggdb -I/usr/local/include/ -I/opt/local/include/ -I/usr/include/ -DVERSION=\"2.09b\" src/http_client.c src/database.c src/crawler.c src/analysis.c src/report.c src/checks.c src/signatures.c src/auth.c -lcrypto -lssl -lidn -lz -lpcre
In file included from src/skipfish.c:47:0:
src/signatures.h:24:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/http_client.c:40:18: fatal error: idna.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/analysis.c:32:0:
src/signatures.h:24:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/signatures.c:27:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [skipfish] Error 1
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are missing dev libraries. Run this command :

```
   sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev  libidn11-dev
```

Comment: how about to install these libs on MacOS X?

Comment: On MacOS X : `brew install pcre` and `brew install libidn`. You need to install brew

Comment: On CentOS `yum install pcre-devel` for pcre.h